# Non-linear secondary xlabel

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a function/dataset, where the secondary x-axis is a function of the primary x-axis, e.g. `1/x` (non-linear). The reason for this is that they are both meaningful parameters. I can set the range correctly by using my "function", however, values in between are different. The following figure shows what is wrong:

[image: Sample figure]

What is wrong here, is that the x2-axis get linearly ticced (is that proper English?). Example: the tic opposite to  1.6 is now 0.7, but should be 0.625 for this case.

Script to reproduce this:

```
xmin=1.
xmax=2.

set xlabel "x"
set xrange [xmin:xmax]

set x2tics
set x2label "1/x"
set x2range [1/xmin:1/xmax]

plot x
```

Is a fancy general way to change the axis-scaling/labeling, other than logarithmic?

Comment: If you are using the 4.7 development version, you can use `set link`, see [gnuplot: how to set custom non linear scales](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18920088/2604213)

Comment: @Christoph Only difference is that in my case the curve should not change, but your link looks interesting!

Comment: That was to show the command `set link`. In that answer it was used as a hack. See http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/linkedaxes.html for a use case similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `do for` approach to loop through a manual label setting (`set x2tics add`).  Here's the edited minimal example you provided (see comments in the script for explanations):

```
xmin=1.
xmax=2.
inc=0.2 # for more control over the tics

f(x)=1./x  # Function that defines the secondary axis
fplot(x)=x # Function that is plot

set xlabel "x"
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set xtics xmin,inc,xmax # specify the actual location for xtics, too

ntics = (xmax-xmin)/inc + 1 # calculate the number of tics
inc2 = (f(xmin)-f(xmax))/(ntics-1) # calculate increment for x2tics

fmin=f(xmin); fmax=f(xmax)
set x2tics fmin,-1*inc2,fmax # set x2tics, labels will be rewritten

# the following loops through the number of tics
# the <set x2tics add ("x2" x2)> command will be repeated
# use arithmetic to calculate the values and the locations
# you need <sprintf> to convert the tic label number into a string

do for [i=1:ntics+1] {
 xtic=xmin+(i-1)*inc
 x2ticpos=f(xmin)-(i-1)*inc2
 set x2tics add (sprintf("%.3g",f(xtic)) x2ticpos)
 }


set x2range [f(xmin):f(xmax)] 

set yrange[fplot(xmin):fplot(xmax)] # you should also specify the yrange, to avoid surprises

plot fplot(x)
```

And the plot you'll get is this:

[image: manual x2 ticks]

Comment: I copied your script, but I am missing the "0.500" tic. If I have to loop run until `ntics+1` it is ok.