# Gnuplot: nonlinear scaling for y axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have 2 datasets which I want to plot on top of each other. The first data set has a yrange of [-10:10], while the second has a range of [-2:2]. If I just plot them on top of each other in the usual linear scale, it is very difficult to see any features of the second data set:

[image: Fig 1]

Ideally I would like a nonlinear scale on the y axis to really emphasise what is going on between -2 and 2. I would like to design a y axis which looks like this:

[image: Fig 2]

So that most of the middle part of the plot is between -2 and 2. (I just manually added ytics in this figure) Does anyone know how to accomplish this via the "set link" command or something similar?

Comment: I wouldn't use some nonlinear scaling of the y-axis. It makes it very difficult for readers to interprete the data. I would use a second y-axis for the smaller plot, `plot "first", "second" axes x1y2`.

Comment: Thanks but I would really like an answer to the question

Comment: The main issue with your suggestion is I want the same scale for the 1st and 2nd dataset so I can see how one correlates with the other. Using 2 different scales (y and y2) would make it hard to see patterns in the data.

Comment: See [gnuplot: how to set custom non linear scales](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18919064/2604213) for an identical question.